# Objective-C Firebase reloadWithCompletion not executing completion code

Tags: objective-c, firebase, authentication

My code is not executing the completion callback after calling reloadWithCompletion

```
if ([FIRAuth auth].currentUser.isEmailVerified) {
    _emailField.text = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.email;
} else {
    [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser reloadWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if ([FIRAuth auth].currentUser.isEmailVerified) {
            _emailField.text = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.email;
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Validation"
                                                        message:@"Your email must be validated to continue."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I fixed the problem but I still don't know why or how the completion code was not working for this user.  I simply used the Firebase Authentication console to delete the user record.  My app then re-created the record and now the completion code executes properly.